# How to turn off water to replace main shutoff on private well

Tags: plumbing, water, well

My mother is on well water. Her main shutoff vale is quite old and nearly impossible to turn. I'd be comfortable replacing it (probably soldering a new one, or for sure a compression fitting) but don't know what to do to stop the water before this main shutoff valve.

I read something about turning off power to the well pump? Assuming I can figure out what breaker that is, is that all I do, and then drain the lines at a low faucet?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, turning off the breaker for the well pump and draining the lines will prevent the water from coming back on and re-pressuring the tank and lines.

I'd put a note on the breaker panel to "stay out" until you are done.